# Bayes' Rule with Constraints

Tags: probability, statistics, bayesian, constraints

[image]

Let's say there are two points on the real line, $x_1$ and $x_2$. We know the distance between them: $d=x_2-x_1$.

We obtain estimates $\tilde{x}_1$ and $\tilde{x}_2$, sampled independently from normal distributions with known variance $\sigma$, and with means $x_1$ and $x_2$ respectively.

What is the best estimate for $x_1$ and $x_2$?

Comment: Interesting question, but it's not at all clear that it has anything to do with Bayes's rule, let alone Bayesianism.

Comment: The question is vague. Do you know which members of the sample came from which distribution? If so, then this is simpler than if you don't.

Comment: I meant in the sense that we know $p(x_1 | \mu_1)$ and $p(x_2 | \mu_2)$, and we wish to find $p(\mu_1, \mu_2 | x_1, x_2)$.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Yes, we know which sample came from which distribution. We can also assume that the estimates preserve the true order, i.e. $\tilde{x}_1<\tilde{x}_2$ if $x_1 < x_2$.

Comment: You say the estimates are sampled from these distributions. Did you mean the estimates are based on samples (each of more than one observation) from these distributions? Or are you taking just one observation from each distribution? Your language is unclear.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Sorry about that. I'll try editing the question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

It looks as if what was intended was a single observation from each distribution, and one knows which came from which distribution. That makes the problem really simple:
\begin{align}
\widetilde{\,x\,}_1 & \sim N(x_1,\sigma^2) \\
\widetilde{\,x\,}_2 & \sim N(x_2,\sigma^2) = N(x_1+d,\sigma^2) \\[12pt]
\text{Therefore} \widetilde{\,x\,}_2 -d & \sim N(x_1,\sigma^2) \quad \text{(Recall that $d$ is known.)}
\end{align}
So
$$
\widetilde{\,x\,}_1,(\widetilde{\,x\,}_2 -d) \sim \operatorname{i.i.d.} N(x_1,\sigma^2).
$$
Therefore the mean of these two observations from that one normal distribution is a reasonable estimator of the population mean $x_1.$

Bayes's rule and Bayesianism are nowhere involved in this, although one could have a prior on $x_1$ and seek a posterior distribution.